# What happened to the grace period?

Tags: support

I've edited the body of this answer ([link to the answer's revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/694747/revisions)) twice after ~21 minutes I initially posted it, the second edit ~3 minutes after the first edit, but the 5 minutes grace period for those two consecutive edits didn't apply; in fact the revision history shows two different revisions, one ~3 minutes after the other (revision 3 ~3 minutes after revision 2).

What happened to the grace period here?

Revision 2: 2015-11-06 **15:02:50**:

[image: screenshot1]

Revision 3: 2015-11-06 **15:05:06**:

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have access to the detailed history, but the [first comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694735/how-would-you-count-every-occurrence-of-a-term-in-all-files-in-the-current-direc/694747#comment1015653_694747) **might** have been added before you edited your question the second time. In that case the grace period ends as soon as the comment is posted.

See [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/267064?s=5|0.0000#267064), there gunr2171 talks about a "new logic".

Comment: Makes sense, I guess that's to protect the poster of the comment from being bashed for apparently foolish comments. Thanks!

Comment: I'd just like to link Shog's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/172297) for reference regarding the rules of the grace period.